# How to implement custom responses in the Watson Virtual Agent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, watson, watson-discovery, watson-virtual-agent

Using the following piece of code we can create the Watson Virtual Again widget:

```
<script src='https://dp1-bot-chat.mybluemix.net/IBMChatClient-v1.1.0.js'></script>
<script>
  IBMChat.init({
    el: 'ibm_chat_root',
    baseURL: 'https://api.ibm.com/virtualagent/run/api/v1',
    botID: '___mybotid___',
    XIBMClientID: '__myclientid____',
    XIBMClientSecret: '___mysecret____'
  });
</script>
```

That works nicely, but how can we add custom responses? Let's say that we want to call a RESTful endpoint (e.g. `api.example.com/foo`)—what are the steps to do that and what should be the data format the endpoint should send?

How to configure this in the Watson Virtual Agent?

The current use-case is that we have a running app using Watson Discovery (which works well), but we need to connect the Watson Virtual Agent to the Watson Discovery.

Because we may want to run some additional code I guess a REST endpoint would be better.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Watson Virtual Agent allows you to modify the text returned from any of the capabilities, disable those capabilities, and now also allows you to link a Conversation workspace which adds custom capabilities to your Agent.  Are you attempting to do one of those three things, or something else?